# AppCompat Library Disadvantages

Tags: android, api, themes, action, android-appcompat

I'm a new Android developer who is trying to find the best balance for API level support. I think my indecision stems from a lack of understanding of the benefits and disadvantages of using the AppCompat Library over newer Android features such as Holo themes and the action bar.

Of course, I know that Holo is unavailable before API Level 14 and the Action Bar is unavailable before API Level 11. If I want to make my apps available to the broader Android userbase, I will need to lower my minSdkVersion and use the AppCompat Library.

My question is, are there any significant recent features of the Android OS that just aren't supported or are unable to be implemented through the AppCompat Library? Adding on to that, if you set your minSdkVersion to say API Level 7 and build your app with support for AppCompat (say, with your app themes being Theme.AppCompat.Light), will devices running an API greater than 11 or 14 for example use default Holo or action bar features or be restricted to AppCompat? I'd like to know if supporting older APIs will disadvantage users with newer and more capable devices.

Anyway, regardless of the outcome, I'll probably still go for supporting say API 7-8. This is more of a curiosity question on my part. I hope it makes sense!

Thanks, Klep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AppCompat should add functionality of the latest API to older APIs when needed. For instance, lollipop added the CardView class, which can be used in older Android APIs when AppCompat is used, with some minor differences (some of the Android L animations may not apply on older versions of Android for example). It is recommended to use AppCompat in most cases, since more users will be able to run your app when you do (depending on your MinSdkVersion). If you want to know what classes you can access in AppCompat, you can take a look at the features [here](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html).

Comment: Cheers for that. In regards to my other question, do you know if users with  more recent OSes will be disadvantaged by using AppCompat? i.e. You said that some of the Android L animations may not be able to replicated through AppCompat, does this mean that if I use AppCompat, my app will not allow Android L animations even for those who can natively support it? Will Android automatically conform these support features into their native features in later APIs if it detects that the user is using the app in a later OS, or will I have to manually do this? Or is this completely idiotic ...

Comment: I wouldn't do this manually, the animations are actually part of the OS's framework. The AppCompat classes are only called when the current OS doesn't have native support for those classes, so when you run the app in Android L, it will use the classes within the framework, if you'd run it on an earlier version, it should use the classes found in the AppCompat library. This means that if you'd set the minSdkVersion to 21, you wouldn't need AppCompat at all, since all the classes are already present in the framework.

Comment: Of course, if you would set MinSdkVersion to 21, you would need at least Android L to be able to run your app, so I wouldn't recommend that either..

Comment: Oh, absolutely, I wouldn't want to do it manually, haha. I was just wondering if it was a core part of the OS, as I expected it would be. Anyway, that was really helpful, thanks very much mate. :)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the *Styles*: through *Platform.AppCompat* style the *Theme.Appcompat* inherits, and then overrides some properties, from Holo (11+) or Material (21+) if these are native on the running device.